# Outputting transactions from a text file to the screen

Tags: c++

Hi I am working on a wage application with four options which are as follows:

1. Subtracts an amount from the shop bank account (The account is text file "shop"). You do not need to add the same amount to 
   another account but you should record the transaction with a timestamp in a separate file. The 
   application should prevent the account balance from becoming overdrawn.
2. List the five most recent transactions to the screen. If there haven’t yet been five transactions 
   then list all of them.
3. Print the account name, number and current balance to the screen.
4. Exit the program.

I have completed 1,3 and 4 but I am completely stumped as to how to go about number 2. I was hoping someone would be able to point me in the right direction.

```
#include <limits>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>


int  read_balance(void);
void write_balance(int balance);

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int selection;
    int total;
    int attempts = 0;
    string name;
    string number;



    cout << "Correct login details entered!" << "" << endl;
    cout << "1. Transfer an amount" <<endl;
    cout << "2. List recent transactions"<<endl;
    cout << "3. Display account details and current balance"<<endl;
    cout << "4.Quit" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter menu number"<<endl;
    cin >> selection;


    switch(selection)
    {
    case 1: 
        cout << "How much do you wish to transfer?" << endl;
        int amount = 0;

        if (std::cin >> amount)
        {
            std::cout << "Transferred Amount:" << amount << "\n";
            int balance = read_balance();

            if (amount <= 0)
            {
                std::cout << "Amount must be positive\n";
            }
            else if (balance < amount)
            {
                std::cout << "Insufficient funds\n";
            }
            else
            {
                int new_balance = balance - amount;

                write_balance(new_balance);
                std::cout << "New account balance: " << new_balance << std::endl;

                fstream infile("time.txt", ios::app);



                std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
                std::string timeresult = std::ctime(&result);


                infile << amount << std::endl;
                infile << timeresult << std::endl;
            }

        }
    break;


    case 2:
        cout << "Here are you're recent transactions" <<endl;
    break;

    case 3:
        cout << "The account names is:" << name << endl;
        cout << "The account number is:" << number << endl;
        std::cout << "The current account balance is " << read_balance() << std::endl;
    break;

    case 4:
        system("pause");
        return 0;

    default:
        cout << "Ooops, invalid selection!" << endl;
        break;

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


int read_balance(void)
{
    std::ifstream f;
    f.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
    f.open("shop.txt");
    int balance;
    f >> balance;
    f.close();
    return balance;
}

void write_balance(int balance)
{
    std::ofstream f;
    f.exceptions(std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit);
    f.open("shop.txt");
    f << balance;
    f.close();
}
```

Comment: Hint - keep a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) of the 5 most recent transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a list of transactions lets say:

```
std::list<std::pair<int,std::string> > last_transactions
```

Write a function that will insert new `pair` at the end of the list every time you process new transaction (`push_back`), and if there are already 6 items in the list it will delete the oldest one (the one at the front - `pop_front`). Than you can use a simple for loop and an iterator to list this transactions.

Comment: think that's a little advanced for me to get my head around at this stage but thanks anyway

Comment: @user3057816 so what are you familiar with at the moment? classes/structures, tables ?

Comment: well I'm studying classes/structures currently but certainly wouldn't say I'm comfortable with them. I think this part of the assignment may just be a little out my reach